# I am new to react and this is my first code. It was working properly and suddenly it showed parsing error(unexpected token at 3:7)module build failed

Tags: javascript

Below is the code that i am using in react js to design a website-

```
    1 | import React from 'react'
    2 |
  > 3 | const App = () => {
      |        ^
    4 |     return (
    5 |         <div
    6 |         </div> 


       export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'

function App(){
    return (<div></div>) 
}

export default App
```

Comment: Updated my code and it still isn't working

Comment: Can you provide the error please?

Comment: Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\localshop\src\App.js: Unexpected token (3:7)

Comment: Have you saved the files before compiling?

Comment: Yes, I have saved my files

Comment: I have edited the code above. Please try it that way.

Comment: Line 2:13:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "(" (2:13)

Comment: this is what it is showing now

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, It is working now. Just deleted everything and rewrote. It works now

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it, if you could mark my answers as correct, so I get the reputation Points. :). Hope you have a nice day.